# Uncatchable Exception (PowerShell)

Tags: exception, powershell, try-catch

I have code that reliably generates an exception.  This is expected so I don't want it to show up at the end of my script when I dump the $error variable to look for actual problems.

Well step 1 is to find this exception and handle it, right?  I can't get that far.  Here is what I've got:

```
Function Add-PowerShellSnapIn($SnapInName){
    Try{
        if ((Get-PSSnapin -Name $SnapInName) -eq $null){
            Write-Warning "SnapIn Is Not Already Loaded"
        }
    }Catch [System.Exception]{
        Write-Warning "Error Caught"
    }
}

Add-PowerShellSnapIn -SnapInName "Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.Admin"
```

If I run this code I can see the exception, but I never see my little "Write-Warning" test message to indicate that the Catch block caught the exception.  I must be missing something here.  Here is the exception I see:

*Get-PSSnapin : No Windows PowerShell snap-ins matching the pattern 'Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.Admin' were found. Check the pattern and then try the command again.
At C:\users\myuser\Desktop\Test.ps1:4 char:20
+         if ((Get-PSSnapin <<<<  -Name $SnapInName) -eq $null){
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (Microsoft.Excha...owerShell.Admin:String) [Get-PSSnapin], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoPSSnapInsFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetPSSnapinCommand*

Edit: Thanks in advance for anyone who takes the time to help me out!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should add `-ErrorAction stop` to your `Get-PSSnapin` to get into the Catch Block.

```
Function Add-PowerShellSnapIn($SnapInName){
    Try{
        if ((Get-PSSnapin -Name $SnapInName -ErrorAction Stop) -eq $null){
            Write-Warning "SnapIn Is Not Already Loaded"
        }
    }Catch [System.Exception]{
        Write-Warning "Error Caught"
    }
}

Add-PowerShellSnapIn -SnapInName "Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.Admin"
```