# How to catch an error from removing a webpart with powershell?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2010

In my sharepoint powershell script:
I am retracting the webpart, then removing the webpart, then adding (and deploying it).
When I retract it, I have to wait until it finishes before I can move on. I am doing an infinite loop and i want to catch the error. If there is error, then wait, and try again, if no error, then break and move on. The issue is that the try catch is not catching the error. (about you can't make a change when theres an ongoing process).

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks.

```
function RETRACT()
{
    ./retractwebpart.ps1
}

function REMOVE()
{
    ./removewebpart.ps1
}

function ADD()
{
    ./addwebpart.ps1
}




RETRACT

do
{
    try 
    {
        REMOVE -ErrorAction Stop
        Break
    }
    Catch [System.Exception] 
    {
        Start-Sleep -m 1000
    }
}
while ($true)

do
{
    try 
    {
        ADD -ErrorAction Stop
        Break
    }
    Catch [System.Exception] 
    {
        Start-Sleep -m 1000
    }
}
while ($true)
```

Retract file

```
# Retracting the solution from web application http://mydomain
Write-Host "Retracting the solution from web application http://mydomain..."
Uninstall-SPSolution –Identity PDFLibrary.wsp –WebApplication http://mydomain -confirm:$false -ErrorAction Stop
```

Remove file

```
# Removing the solution from web application http://mydomain
Write-Host "Removing the solution from web application http://mydomain..."
Remove-SPSolution –Identity PDFLibrary.wsp -confirm:$false -ErrorAction Stop
```

Add file

```
# Adding the solution to SharePoint
Write-Host "Adding the solution to SharePoint..."
Add-SPSolution C:/PDFLibrary/PDFLibrary.wsp

# Deploying the solution to web application http://mydomain
Write-Host "Deploying the solution to web application http://mydomain..."
Install-SPSolution –Identity PDFLibrary.wsp –WebApplication http://mydomain –GACDeployment
```

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18500423/uncatchable-exception-powershell

Comment: Where can I attach ` -ErrorAction Stop` to? I tried 
`REMOVE -ErrorAction Stop` but I get the same result...

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Its the generic error you get when you try to remove something when its not retracted. The issue is that its not going into the catch block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to duplicate your issue and gave it a try.  This time I removed `-ErrorAction Stop` and it still went into the `Catch` Block. The trick may be I think is to have Catch [System.Exception] block in place (not sure because in attempt 3 I removed `-ErrorAction` and `[System.Exception]` and it still went into Catch block. And just as Hyper Anthony suggested in the comment `-ErrorAction Stop` is supported in all commands so it should work.  The script in the following function throws error on purpose to test the logic.  I think your RETRACT function is throwing error.

**Attempt1** -Without -ErrorAction

```
Function Remove
{
 C:\scripts\so\DeletedFiles.ps1 
}
try
{
 Remove
}
Catch [System.Exception]{
Write-Host "Unhandled Exception occurred"
}
```

It works fine - Lands into Catch Block.

**Attempt2** With -ErrorAction Stop

```
Function Remove
{
 C:\scripts\so\DeleteFiles.ps1 
}
try
{
 Remove -ErroAction Stop
}
Catch [System.Exception]{
Write-Host "Unhandled Exception occurred"
}
```

It works fine and lands into Catch block.

**Attempt3**

```
Function Remove
{
 C:\scripts\so\DeletedFiles.ps1 
}
try
{
 Remove
}
Catch{
Write-Host "Unhandled Exception occurred"
}
```

It still works and lands into Catch block.

After all these attempts I am believing that your `RETRACT` function is throwing error which is outside the try catch block.

Comment: I updated my code above. I actually have a print statement in the REMOVE function import file. And it gets printed, so it is executing the remove function when it crashes.

Comment: may be if you post more details about your functions it could help.

Comment: ok, I put the contents of the three files above. When I run the script, I get the print statement about retracting, then right after I get the print statement about removing (`"Removing the solution from web application http://mydomain..."`). Then I get the red error message.

Comment: now it works. I put the error action stop in the functions in the imported files.

Comment: Nice. I was looking into trap function of powershell too in the meanwhile. It also does something similar. Mark it as answer if it solves your problem.